# Receiving Google Voice calls to my EVO

Tags: google-voice

I recently set up a GV number and seemingly activated the number for my cell phone, HTC Evo. I can make outgoing calls using the GV# and send/receive texts fine but whenever someone calls the number it gives an 'unable to connect' error and hangs up. Anyone have a solution for this issue?

Comment: This works on my EVO. Did you set up your GV# to forward to your cell number? You might need to log into GV from a computer (or at least the phone's browser) to check.

Comment: @eldarerathis Pretty sure that is it, I suggest posting it as an answer :)

Comment: I have already set up forwarding to my mobile and activated it by calling in *28.... I can make calls already from my cell. I also setup my voicemail recording.

Comment: I don't think *28 sets up forwarding from your GV# to your cell. That is for (as far as I know) forwarding from your cell number to wherever you want in the event that you do not answer or are out of service.

Comment: @Matthew: Yeah, I still don't know if it's the actual problem, but it's my best guess at this point. Went ahead and posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is still just my best guess, but I would definitely check to be sure that Google Voice is linked to your cell number and that it is set up to forward your calls. You should see something like this in your settings:

[image]

If that's all set up properly then you might want to consider starting a discussion thread over at [Google's support forum](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Mobile/label?lid=593d4f8493a8b7b7&hl=en).

Comment: Mine looks just like that in my GV account. I'm nearly certain it's set up right. I must be missing something. Only been set up for 24 hours though, but I doubt it is about time.

Comment: The google forum shows that sprint phones making calls into GV get this error. all my tests have been from sprint devices so I will have to try outside sprint.